# C++ Sized template deduction

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I want to create a wrapper around with std::array with some extended functionality. The class should be instantiable via an `std::initializer_list`. I also need a constructor to which I can pass an existing instance of the class plus a "suffix", meaning that the instance need to be of size + 1.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <array>
#include <initializer_list>

template<size_t L>
class JsonPointer {
public:
   constexpr JsonPointer(std::array<const char*, L> segments)
        : m_path_segments(std::move(segments))
    {
    }

    constexpr JsonPointer(std::initializer_list<const char*> list) : m_path_segments(std::array<const char*, list.size()>)
    {
    }

    template<size_t S>
    JsonPointer(JsonPointer<S> existing, const char* suffix)  {
    }

private:
    std::array<const char*, L> m_path_segments;
};

int main(){
    constexpr JsonPointer base_ptr {"a", "n"};
    auto ptr = JsonPointer(base_ptr, "test");
}
```

How can I use the size of `std::initializer_list` for constexpr initialization? In the "expansion", how can I make the deducation realize that `S=L+1`?

Comment: And you still need the ordinary copy constructor for the case no suffix is added – suppose you can just default it.

Comment: I'm a bit worried about all those `char const*` pointers – if some of are created dynamically, which instance will be the owner of? Which one will delete them again if not needed any more to avoid memory leaks?

Comment: For the constructor, try `JSonPointer(JSonPointer<L-1> existing, const char *suffix)` instead of your one templated on `S`.   You will also need a specialisation of your class for `L` equal to zero.

Comment: @Peter Tried that myself already, but doesn't allow automatic deduction of `L`, see [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/xn6EK9oaY). Additionally `std::array` covers already the case of [`N == 0`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), so the specialisation here might not be necessary.

Comment: @Aconcagua  The specialisation is necessary because declaring such a constructor means that instantiating `JSonPointer<N>`  instantiates `JSonPointer<N-1>` which causes an infinite recursion or loop (e.g. in the compiler) - an explicit specialisation is needed to stop that recursive relationship. Some compilers will detect that recursion, other compilers simply crash.  [With a `size_t` the recursion depth is technically finite (equal to `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()`) but exceeds capacity of real-world compilers].

Comment: @Peter Indeed... Still deduction of `L` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with C++20 you can achieve this by adding 2 [user defined deduction guides](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction#User-defined_deduction_guides):

```
template<typename... Ts>
JsonPointer(Ts... ts)->JsonPointer<sizeof...(Ts)>;

template<size_t S>
JsonPointer(JsonPointer<S> existing, const char* suffix)->JsonPointer<S + 1>;
```

they allow the compiler to find the correct deduction without naming the full template.

---

```
template<size_t L>
class JsonPointer {
public:
    constexpr JsonPointer(std::array<const char*, L> segments)
        : m_path_segments(std::move(segments))
    {
    }

    constexpr JsonPointer(std::initializer_list<const char*> list) : m_path_segments() {
        std::copy(list.begin(), list.end(), this->m_path_segments.begin());
    }

    template<size_t S>
    constexpr JsonPointer(JsonPointer<S> existing, const char* suffix) : m_path_segments() {
        std::copy(existing.m_path_segments.begin(), existing.m_path_segments.end(), 
            this->m_path_segments.begin());
        this->m_path_segments.back() = std::move(suffix);
    }

    template<size_t S>
    friend class JsonPointer;
private:
    std::array<const char*, L> m_path_segments;
};

template<typename... Ts>
JsonPointer(Ts... ts)->JsonPointer<sizeof...(Ts)>;

template<size_t S>
JsonPointer(JsonPointer<S> existing, const char* suffix)->JsonPointer<S + 1>;

int main() {
    constexpr JsonPointer base_ptr{ "a", "n" };
    constexpr auto ptr = JsonPointer(base_ptr, "test");
}
```

---

the `constexpr ptr` now holds `{"a", "n", "test"}`

[try it out](https://godbolt.org/z/dajePWPY3)

Comment: Very cool, but I am unfortunately I am stuck with C++17, this seems to require c++20.

Comment: When removing the `constexpr` from the last 2 constructors it does work except for the `std::initializer_list` one (due to constexprness of std::copy).

Comment: Rolling my own version of std::copy which can be made constexpr seems to do the trick: https://godbolt.org/z/Y6dfPMc84. Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction :^)